# AngularJS: Persistent Error with $sessionStorage

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to store the count of the score using $sessionStorage, for some reason, the assignment operation. Also, I cannot assign $sessionStorage variable with anything else as well.

`$sessionStorage.score = parseInt($sessionStorage.score) + 1;//gives error`

```
$scope.x = 0;
$sessionStorage.score = $scope.x; // also gives error
```

Also,

```
$sessionStorage.score = JSON.stringify($scope.x);// gives error
```

how to resolve this?

Comment: Please add more code. Probably you didn't inject $sessionStorage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use "sessionStorage" instead of "$sessionStorage".

Comment: Thanks siva, that was it.